# Limiting access to webservices so only my applicaiton can use it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I have a system which will update some UI details regarding user notification every X seconds (just like StackOverflow's notification, gmail inbox and so on).
I am planing to have a webservice that will check for new notifications and have it called every X seconds. The fact is: I do not want to make it public for everyone, I want to make it accessible only to my system, so it is the only one able to consume it.

Is there any way to do that? Using a WebService is not required, if you have other approach I would like to hear it.

My system is built using ASP.NET 4.0 and Microsoft's MVC framework. Could I call an action to do that?

My question is similar to this: [How do I secure ASP.NET web service to only allow relative path calling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866653/how-do-i-secure-asp-net-web-service-to-only-allow-relative-path-calling)

But as far as I understood the answer, he proposed that the webservice could be turned into an ordinary class method inside the system that is not accessible from outside. This does not work for me because I want to access it from the client side.

Thanks,
Oscar

ps: changing infrastructure configs (ex: hosting it in an internal server) would be hard to do...

EDIT: what I want to achieve with this webservice is to update the notifications number. This should be done without refreshing the page, for this reason I thought about verifying with the server if there are any notifications and, if there are, update the UI.

Edit2: I could transform this webmethod in an ordinary method inside my system, that would be no problem. The question would then change to **How do I wire the client to this method?** Maybe calling an action using javascript and then inside this action calling the method?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy this WebService on a different web site and then [configure this site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733090%28WS.10%29.aspx) to be accessible only from IP : `127.0.0.1`. Also checkout [this blog post](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/locking-down-website-access-by-ip-in-iis7) - you could install the `IP Security` and then:

> Lastly, to create the restrictions, open up the IIS Manager and select
>   the website that you want to restrict. Open the IP Address and Domain
>   Restrictions module, and then in the actions panel (on the right side)
>   choose Edit Feature Settings.... To only allow local browsing, you
>   should deny by default. Choose Deny from the dropdown, and hit OK.
>   Then add your exceptions -- the IP's or ranges that you want to allow
>   access to. To do that, choose Add Allow Entry... from the action
>   panel, and add all the exceptions you need.

Now, only applications running on the same web server can access this web service.

Comment: that would be good, but I am using hosting services like AppHarbor that do not give me this kind of flexibility.... Any other ideas? As said before, this implementing this feature as a web service is not mandatory...

Comment: Ohh, then simply don't implement it as a web service. Make it part of a class library that only your MVC application will have access to.

Comment: that could be done, but how would I "wire" the client side to the library call? I would create an MVC action that would be called by the client using javascript and  will call the methods in the class library?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. You don't necessarily need to use javascript to access an action. You could use a simple html `<form>` or even an anchor. It will all depend on what you need. But, yes, it is the controller action that could serve as a bridge.

Comment: Sorry, the question is missing information. Please see the edit.
I want to update the "notification count" if the user receives notifications without refreshing the page (just like facebook). To do that I thought in calling a webservice (or similar) and update the UI elements in case of new notifications